# Como puedo poner un background tipo slider en mi web?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, slider

Quiero poner un background que se mueva con un estilo slider, y que tenga cierta opacidad para que el contenido principal se pueda notar perfectamente, habria una forma en codigo claro, de hacerlo?

he intentado con javascript y css pero nada me ha resultado.

Answer (score 1):

vi este codigo por alli

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.slider-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height:600px;
  position: relative;
}
.single-slide {
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
animation: slider-animation;
animation-duration: 25s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  background-size: cover;
}

#slide-1 {background-color: red; background-image: url(https://images7.alphacoders.com/391/391001.jpg);}
#slide-2 {background-color: rebeccapurple; animation-delay: 5s; background-image: url(https://images5.alphacoders.com/426/426029.jpg);}
#slide-3 {background-color: orange; animation-delay: 10s; background-image: url(http://www.amazingwallpaperz.com/wp-content/uploads/Ice-Cream-Wallpapers-For-Laptops.jpg);}
#slide-4 {background-color: blue; animation-delay: 15s; background-image: url(http://wallpapersdsc.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Ice_Cream_Iphone_wallpapers14.jpg);}
#slide-5 {background-color: green; animation-delay: 20s; background-image: url(http://kingofwallpapers.com/ice-cream-wallpaper/ice-cream-wallpaper-015.jpg);}

@keyframes slider-animation {
    
0% {
    opacity: 0;
}
6% {
    opacity: 1;
}
24% {
    opacity: 1;
}
30% {
    opacity: 0;
}
100% {
    opacity: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-wrap">
  <div class="single-slide" id="slide-1"></div>
  <div class="single-slide" id="slide-2"></div>
  <div class="single-slide" id="slide-3"></div>
  <div class="single-slide" id="slide-4"></div>
  <div class="single-slide" id="slide-5"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Esto funciona, claro, pero dentro de el div con la clase slider-wrap, en mi caso quiero que sea toda la pagina que tenga el background, osea en el body.

Comment: por lo que entiendo la propiedad opacity es lo que le da transparencia a una imagen, coloca esa propiedad en el body

Comment: Si lo hace, pero como te imaginaras, le daria un opacity a todos los elementos incluyendo menus, contenido, etc...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662178/opacity-of-divs-background-without-affecting-contained-element-in-ie-8